# Given an ID, find and replace the last sentence with a span wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

Given the following:

```
<div id="bigchuck">
 <p>blah blah blah.</p>
 <p>yada yada yada.</p>
 <p>Tada. Bing bong the witch is dead. Door bell.</p>
</div>
```

How can JavaScript/JQUERY find the last sentence "Door bell" and wrap it with a  tag, to result in:

```
<div id="bigchuck">
 <p>blah blah blah.</p>
 <p>yada yada yada.</p>
 <p>Tada. Bing bong the witch is dead. <span>Door bell.</span></p>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: if all you want is change the "Door bell" area. you can put a special tag with a assigned id, then you can do your manipulation against the Id

Comment: It's going to be dynamic, as the user is typing they can trigger this function, so I won't have an ID

Answer (score 3):

This solution is based on patrick's solution (he deserves the credit for coming up with the `function(i,html)` approach), but it just wraps the last sentence and not the space before it:

```
$('#bigchuck p:last').html( function(i,html) {
  var arr = html.split(". ");
  arr[arr.length-1]="<span>"+arr[arr.length-1]+"</span>";
  return arr.join(". ");
});
```

Here's the [code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/cdrDN/).

Comment: Gert +1 Very nice. Using `.html( function() {} )` is just a shortcut. It's the guts of the function that matters. I like your solution better. :o)

Comment: Thanks patrick. :) Well, I learned a new approach from you. I think that's the beauty with SO. You learn something new every day. :)

Comment: Gert - Indeed. I've acquired a good part of my jQuery knowledge here.

Comment: @patrick - Same here. Earlier today I watched Scott Hanselman's "Social Networking for Developers" (http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/ch9/3/2/1/1/6/5/HanselminutesOn9SocialNetworkingForDevs1_ch9.wmv). He talked about - among other things - SO, Jon Skeet and how everyone needs at least three places in life. He also talked about how SO is a leap forward compared to the old discussion forums, where you have to dig through all the posts to find the answers. Sorry for going off-topic, but it's a good video and what he says about SO is very true.

Comment: Gert - Cool. Thanks for the link. I'll be sure to check it out.

Comment: Challenge,,, After code runs it's moving the mouse cursor. Any ideas what would be doing that? And if there's a way to prevent it or put it back so the user can keep typing?

Comment: Another issue is that it's wrapping incorrectly it's doing: <p>Blah Blah <span> blah blah</p></span> where the span should be before the </p>. Are you seeing this too?

Comment: @WozPoz - In which browser are you experiencing this?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var plast = $("#bigchuck").find("p:last").text();

var part = plast.split("."), pos = part.length - 2;
if (part.length < 2)
  pos = 0;

part[pos] = "<span>" + part[pos] + ".</span>";
part.pop(); // <-edit for comment

$("#bigchuck").find("p:last").html(part.join("."));
```

Comment: You're ending up with an extra `.` at the end. I was originally having the same trouble with the final `.` being outside the span.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:** http://jsfiddle.net/NpjUt/

```
$('#bigchuck p:last').html( function(i,html) {
    var arr = html.split(/(\.)/);
    arr.splice(arr.length - 3, 0, '<span>');
    arr.push('</span>')
    return arr.join('');
});
```

​

Comment: @patrick - I hope you don't mind me adding the second version. It will wrap just the text and not the space in front of the first word in the last sentence.

Comment: @Gert - It's a good solution. You should go ahead and add it as an answer. I'd vote for it! :o)

Comment: @Gert - That is very gracious and considerate of you, but the solution is unique enough that it is really yours. I was stuck on the last `.` issue. Yours solves it nicely. I'm going to roll mine back, and will expect to see your answer shortly. :o) You can note that it builds off of mine if you prefer.

Comment: @patrick - Thanks. :) But I still think you deserve upvotes for coming up with the `function(i,html)` approach. My first solution was way more bombastic.

Comment: @Gert - Yeah, passing a function was a nice addition to jQuery 1.4. Good thing about your solution is that it doesn't split on the last `.`, which was giving me a hard time. I didn't even think to add a space in there. Solves that issue perfectly and simplifies the code.